# Is there a way to configure the way UML diagrams present methods (by name) in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, uml, class-diagram

I'm creating UML diagrams for someone else's code, using the diagramming tools in `PyCharm Professional 2018.2.4`.

When selecting to show methods, it shows ALL methods. Is there was a to configure the diagramming tool to show only methods of a certain match, or at least only public methods (not hidden)?

I.e.

[image]